# Undefined function 'head' in Matlab

Tags: matlab, toolbox, undefined-function

I have encountered a strange problem. 
I receive this error while running my code:

Undefined function 'head' for input arguments of type 'table'.

```
filename = 'C:\\Users\\farazpc.ir\\Downloads\\Telegram 
Desktop\\MainDataset.csv';
m = readtable(filename);
h = head(m,500);
```

Although I have checked with **ver** and **which** commands and I have this function and I have tried to set a path for this method from Home in Matlab then set path part. I followed the instructions from this link:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-functions.html

Here is the path for the head method:

```
 which head

 H:\signal matlab\toolbox\matlab\bigdata\@tall\head.m  % tall method
```

My Matlab version is 2016b.
I am really confused and need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks liek a different fucntion from a different toolbox that is called the same. You are not using `tall` arrays, you are using tables. If that is the only one you have, then it means you dont have the required toolbox

Comment: can you try using a simpler filename? I would suggest cd into the directory where the csv is and run readtable('MainDataset.csv');, see if this works around the rpoblem

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz That's very unlikely, given that the error is for an undefined function `head`, not a failed file load using `readtable`, a sensible assumption is the table was read successfully...

Comment: head is mistaken for an input argument. it is possible that parsing filename to two or more parts resulted in more than one input argument.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind responses. The problem was head method was not the one That I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `head` which you expect is the tabular method, introduced in MATLAB R2016b (as stated at the bottom of the [docs page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/head.html)).

**My guess would be you're using a MATLAB version older than R2016b.**

Across all toolboxes, there are in fact 4 head functions (as of R2017b), you can get the available functions listed by using the `-all` argument for `which`:

```
>> which head -all
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\bigdata\@tall\head.m              % tall method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@tabular\head.m         % tabular method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\head.m  % codistributed method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\@gpuArray\head.m            % gpuArray method
```

Because you don't have the tabular method, there is no defined function `head` for input type `table` - only for tall array data types (or anything else you have the toolbox for).

---

**Workaround**

A quick workaround is to just use indexing

```
h = m( 1:500, : ); % Get first 500 rows of m, for all columns
```

If your table might not have enough rows, add some protection:

```
h = m( 1:min(500,size(h,1)), : ); % Get first 500 rows (or all rows if <500)
```

This is basically what the desired `head` function does anyway...

---

As directed in the [MATLAB tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info) (or tag info) on this site, please always specify which release version you're using, it helps diagnose problems exactly like this one!

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Yes, I did not have the head "tabular method" but, my Matlab version is 2016b.

Comment: @m.erfani If you have R2016b then you should have `head` for tables, it is in core MATLAB and doesn't require any toolboxes. You can still use my suggested work-around, but note that your MATLAB installation may have an issue if what you say is true!

Comment: `head` was added first only for `tall` arrays, the `table` implementation was only added later.

Comment: Is there a way to add updated methods to R2016b without Installing new version?

Comment: @m.erfanim nope, that's the incentive to get the new version. Not worth it for `head`, the indexing option I've shown is literally the same functionality

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, I used your way and it works fine and thanks to you for that. Upgrading to the new version is just a little bothering:) Thank you anyway.